# Several issues with Gradle

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I'm sorry if i'm not being specific but I have many issues and I can't find the solution to them. When I try to run the app, it appears I have 3 problems with the gradle.

### **1- 1: Task failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Build cancelled while executing task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

### **2-2: Task failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform firebase-storage-19.2.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4fe024a2b334d8544f8eaa9cab7ed523\jetified-firebase-storage-19.2.1.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4fe024a2b334d8544f8eaa9cab7ed523\jetified-firebase-storage-19.2.1

> Failed to transform picasso-2.71828.aar (com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\404382cef99e8c07ee7e6c1551073a5c\jetified-picasso-2.71828.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\404382cef99e8c07ee7e6c1551073a5c\jetified-picasso-2.71828

> Failed to transform firebase-firestore-22.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1b5a9ebef469875d1d39c8e5b85769d9\jetified-firebase-firestore-22.1.1.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1b5a9ebef469875d1d39c8e5b85769d9\jetified-firebase-firestore-22.1.1

> Failed to transform exifinterface-1.0.0.aar (androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f6c88b0a3ddf6df8293f03115fc9af5d\exifinterface-1.0.0.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f6c88b0a3ddf6df8293f03115fc9af5d\exifinterface-1.0.0

> Failed to transform protolite-well-known-types-17.1.1.aar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.1.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e53fbbcf78ffb18c7cd795b35d4efb56\jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.1.1.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e53fbbcf78ffb18c7cd795b35d4efb56\jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.1.1

> Failed to transform grpc-android-1.28.0.aar (io.grpc:grpc-android:1.28.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\10a3513949333938587db48c8411373d\jetified-grpc-android-1.28.0.
> > Build cancelled while executing AarTransform: C:\Users\DobleClick.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\10a3513949333938587db48c8411373d\jetified-grpc-android-1.28.0

### **3- 3: Task failed with an exception.**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Build cancelled while executing task ':app:processDebugResources'

And here is my gradle.

````
   id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 30
   buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.firebaselognreg"
       minSdkVersion 16
       multiDexEnabled true
       targetSdkVersion 30
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"

       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.1'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha01'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ```
````

Comment: First option is always: 1. Clean and rebuild your project 2. File -> Invalidate Cache and restart. Have you tried that? Or what else have you tried?

Comment: Seems like jcenter is down at the moment.
I get code 500 returned when I try to build my app.

https://status.bintray.com/

Comment: @javdromero what do you mean by "cleaning" the project and invalidate cache? :C I've only tried updating my libraries

Comment: Assuming you are using Android Studio, Option 1. click Build -> Clean project, when it's finished Build -> Make project. Option 2. click File -> Invalidate cache/restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: @javdromero Thanks!! The first option help :D thank u so much, u just saved my life xd